# How to wait for multiple listeners with timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout, listener

I'm having the following problem:

The main thread runs code (that is being called a few times every second) of my application, and at some point it notifies a list of listeners before performing a certain action. The listeners then perform actions in order to collect data from an external source, some of these actions are time consuming.

Now, on one hand I want to give each listener the chance to be able to complete it's job before I keep running the main thread (because the data might be lost or changed after the action is done), and on the other hand I need to limit the entire notifying-collecting process to a certain timeout, in order to maintain a reasonable flow of the actions.

Anyway, I want any listener that didn't have the time to finish it's job to continue.

Some example code:

```
public class ExampleTimeoutNotifier {
    private static ArrayList<ExampleTimeoutNotifierListener> listeners;
    private static int timeOutInMillis;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        timeOutInMillis = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        // ... the following code is being called repeatedly on the main thread:

            // How to limit the process timeout?
            for (ExampleTimeoutNotifierListener l : listeners) {
                l.collectBeforeAction();
            }

        // Do the action...
    }

    public interface ExampleTimeoutNotifierListener {
        public void collectBeforeAction();
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you should look into synchronized if I understood what you mean. here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: @CME64 can you explain how this can help? I don't have concurrency issues, and don't care to lock any object or data.

Comment: that's what I understood from your statement "I want to give each listener the chance to be able to complete it's job before I keep running the main thread (because the data might be lost or changed after the action is done)" correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: oh wait, you want to continue running in the main body after the thread is executed ? ,, in that case it should not be a thread, rather a function instead will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I am using, and it seems to work just fine.
I won't mark it as my choice for now, because I'm not sure I'm doing it the right way...

```
final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
ArrayList<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();

for (final ExampleTimeoutNotifierListener l : listeners) {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                l.collectBeforeAction();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    };
    t.start();
    threads.add(t);
}

for (Thread t : threads) {
    try {
        long timeoutLeft = timeOutInMillis - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        if (timeoutLeft < 1) break;
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}
```